# Show tags that are the same as the title of the custom post wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I'm at a loss. On my single{custom-post-type}.php I want to create a loop that first shows the title of the page and the content. But then it also generates a list with all the content from a tag that had the same name as the title of the page.

Can somebody help me on the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance of [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to query the posts inside the taxonomy term with the same name as the title. This is done by adding the `tax_query` field to the arguements.

```php
<?php
// WordPress header
get_header();
the_post();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom-post-type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // -1 retrieves all the posts the query finds.
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category', // This is the default 'post' taxonomy, if you are using a custom taxonomy then you need to change this.
            'field'    => 'name', // Use name as you want to match the title
            'terms'    => get_the_title(), // Get the title of the current post as a string.
        )
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()):
    while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); // Loop through the posts from the term with same name as current post title. ?>
        <article class="post">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset usage of 'the_post()'
endif;

<?php get_footer();
```